# Firestore: Query clause where current date is less than due date doesn't work with rule that performs the same check

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection `elements` with documents that contain `start` date (timestamp data type) and `end` date (timestamp data type).
If I want to get all `elements` which `end` date is greater than today, I do:

```js
firebase.firestore().collection('elements').where('end', '>', new Date()).get();
```

This works perfectly. Now I want to add a rule with the same check on firestore, to prevent that a malicious user could perform this request with `new Date()` containing a past date and return expired documents.

I added the following rule to firestore:

```js
match /elements/{document=**} {
  allow read: resource.data.end > request.time
}
```

Now all the queries return `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions` and I can't understand why. The query is requesting for all elements that end date is greater than today's date, and the rule is verifying that document's end date is greater than server time. In my mind this should work.

Comment: I'm immediately suspicious of the difference in the time on your client and on the server. To rule that out, can you try passing `.where('end', '>', Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now() + 24*60*60*1000))`. If that works, we'll know the problem is caused by some offset (of the client and/or timezones).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly that the client machine's clock does not match the Google server's clock.  If the client clock is running even slightly faster than Google's clock, the rule will deny the query.

You could try adding some padding from the date to add a reasonable offset from the current time:

```js
// add 10 seconds from current time so as not to undershoot the end
.where('end', '>', new Date(Date.now() + 10000))
```

While this might work OK for clients whose clocks are reasonably in sync with world standards, it could still fail if the client's clock is still way off.

Comment: I thought this wasn't going to change anything because all the `end` dates were days ahead of today, but may be related to something I read elsewhere:

"Firebase is validating that the query matches the rules, then runs the query if it passes."

In my case, I was requesting with a Date ahead of request.time, so that rule won't always be true, even if there weren't expirated documents, firebase still drops the query.

Comment: For some reason, in my case with '<', the query returns results with empty date string (`""`) as well which is undesired. And, what if the date is stored in two different formats, `DD/MM/YYYY` and `DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a`? because it seems to work only with the first one.